# error: ‘NULL’ undeclared

Tags: c

Файл null.c.

```
int main() {
    void *p = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Собираю, используя gcc.

```
$ gcc null.c
```

Получаю ошибку.

> null.c: In function ‘main’:
> null.c:2: error: ‘NULL’ undeclared
> (first use in this function)

Что не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NULL не является ключевым словом. Это макроопределение заданное в стандартных заголовках. Чтобы его использовать нужно подключить их.

```
#include <stddef.h>
```

Comment: А ещё лучше честно написать нолик и не мучиться :)

Comment: Бородатые дяди говорят, что это дурной тон.